# command line arguments works in visual studio but not from command line for a WindowsForm project in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, command-line-arguments

I've done a little programm in visual basic.
It compress a file and upload the file on an ftp server. The programm himself work well.

My problem is that i want it to have a different behavior if it takes arguments from command line or not. If arguments are given no form shows up and if not the form is loaded.

The code getting command line arguments work fine when executed from visual basic (project properties -> debug -> start options -> command line arguments is set with the file path)

But when i execute the program from cmd with this line :
pogram.exe C:\Users\user\file.txt

The form shows up and no arguments are detected.

Here is the main for dispatch.
Module1.vb :

```
   Module Module1

Declare Function AttachConsole Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwProcessId As Int32) As Boolean
Declare Function FreeConsole Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Boolean

Sub Main()
    Dim cmdArgs As String() = GetCommandLineArgs()
    Form2.loadData()
    If cmdArgs.Length = 0 Then ' NO ARGS MODE
        mainWindow.commandLineMode = False
        Application.Run(mainWindow)
    ElseIf cmdArgs.Length < 3 And Form2.TXTnumLicence.Text = "" Then ' BAD ARGS NUMBER
        Console.WriteLine("Aucun numero de licence definit. Usage : ./ODG_exchange ['filePath'] [numeroLicence [default = ./ODG_param.xml > numero_licence]]")
        Application.Exit()
    Else ' ARGS MODE
        mainWindow.commandLineMode = True
        mainWindow.commandeLine(cmdArgs)
    End If
End Sub
```

In visual studio i also defined the startup object as Module1. Maybe it will be useful.

Comment: `GetCommandLineArgs` is [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx), correct?

Comment: That's indeed fishy.  Also "defined startup object as Module1", that's not possible.  This question has too many discrepancies.

Comment: Environment.GetCommandLineArgs indeed.

I guess it is possible to set startup object has Module1 since i did it.

EDIT : I looked closer why you say that it's not possible, i disabled application framework checkbox in project properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well 7 days later i found the solution... Just use the good .exe and it works as well as in visual studio...

I feel so dumb, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There is always one command line arg - the filename of the executing program.
You need to change your if statement to cmdArgs.length = 1

Comment: Indeed. I used args in an other way before, i modified the rest of the code but forgot this line.

I fixed it but it still doesn't work.
Thanks for the try